# Add class decorator to inherit parent docs

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, decorator, python-decorators

I am trying to add a util to my package where a subclass will inherit the superclasses's docstring. Here is what I set up so far.

```
from functools import wraps
import typing as t


def inherit_parent_docs(klass):
    @wraps(klass)
    def inside(*args: t.Any, **kwargs: t.Any):
        parent_doc = B.__bases__[0].__doc__
        klass.__doc__ += parent_doc
        klass_out = klass(*args, **kwargs)
        return klass_out

    return inside

class A:
    """super"""

@inherit_parent_docs
class B(A):
    """sub"""
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

However, this does not work because it says `B` doesn't have `bases` dunder because it thinks its a function. And I checked, strangely enough, `type(B)` is `function`. Also I tried wrapping the constructor, but then the docstring is only updated when instantiated.

I feel like I am missing something obvious here...

Comment: Why are you using `B` there and not `klass.__bases__[0].__doc__`? It seems odd to use a global variable like that in a decorator since it would only properly apply to `B`.

Comment: That is a bug from me quickly creating a reproducible sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that is what decoration does. It assigned the function, `inside` to `B`.

So when you

```
@inherit_parent_docs
class B(A):
    ...
```

That is syntactic sugar for:

```
class B(A):
    ...
B = inherit_parent_docs(B)
```

Note, you could just not return a `wrapper`. Return *the `Klass`* after you've modified it:

```
def inherit_parent_docs(klass):
    doc = klass.__doc__
    parent_doc = klass.__bases__[0].__doc__
    klass.__doc__ = f"{doc}\n{parent_doc}\n"
    return klass
```